# best practice to config aws IAM user for each aws services in production deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I'm working on netcore 2.1 web api project. I need using S3 and SNS aws services. I'm tending to use two IAM users for each service. What is the best practice to config IAM user (accesskey and accesssecret), each user for each aws service for example in netcore api project?

Comment: Why are you using "two IAM users for each service"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best practice to config IAM user (Accesskey and  secret keys).

There is no (Accesskey and Secret key) in best practice, only [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), if you are working inside AWS and you are running your application on AWS services like Ec2 or ECS etc, never ever use keys I will always prefer [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) inside AWS, your code will not dependent on hard coded keys and you will not worry about the management of keys.

> I'm tending to use two IAM users for each service

If both project running inside one Ec2 instance better to use single IAM role and the role have permission to both services like **S3 and SNS**, there is no single advantage of separating using secret keys and access keys because both projects are running in the same machine.

If both projects running on a different machine then the idea make sense and then create TWO IAM role one for s3 and one for SNS and assigning the required role for each machine.

specify the action in the role that project can perform on a particular s3 or SNS topic, for example

```
        {
            "Sid": "prod-sns",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:06012345678:prod-*"
        }
```

Once you assign this role, the prod server will able to perform all action on only SNS topic that is start from `prod` or you can create them more specific.

you can read more about SNS and s3 policy here.

[sns-topic-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/sns-topic-policy.html)

[example-bucket-policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)